# Custom app installer like Ninite?

Tags: installer

I'm looking for something similar to [Ninite](http://ninite.com/), that would let me package tools we use in our dev environment without having to go out and download each separately. Is there something out there that does this (preferably at no cost)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say what you are looking for is [Ninite Pro](https://ninite.com/pro)

> Ninite Pro installers run 3 times faster than normal Ninite installers because they save and reuse downloaded apps in the Ninite Cache. The cache is used automatically and stays up-to-date as new versions of apps are released.
>
> The default location for the cache is the same folder the Ninite Pro installer is in. So you can just drop Ninite One on your USB key and you'll have an ultra-fast installer you can bring with you from machine to machine. It's that that simple.

There are various [alternatives to Ninite](http://alternativeto.net/software/ninite/) but they're not particularly forthcoming about whether they operate from a local cached copy.  The main one [allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/) has a painfully slow website so I couldn't find out that much about it.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at that. The $20/month price tag is pretty hefty for something that will be used once in a great while.

Comment: @Sergei I've added an alternative, but not sure if it has the features you're after as the website is slow for me...

Comment: @Sergei Greate question. I am wondering why microsoft/other os manufacturer don't provide such a solution. It would be much more feasible from a user side to install lots of application.

Comment: @newcomer, I haven't found anything that allows to create custom packages with simple drag and drop UI. Essentially what i wanted to do is bundle a bunch of installation packages together into 1 executable to install them all at once. I was able to do that with Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Pretty easy to bang out any installation. You'll have to write a tiny custom script, but it's very easy to do.

Comment: @Sergei : Excellent! I think you should post this comment as Answer. It is the solution :)

Comment: @sergei, I have edited my answer so if you have a proper answer you should be able to un-accept mine and accept the proper solution. If it is your own answer you may have to wait a day or two to accept your own answer though.

Comment: If you have a Software storage folder on your network, Ninite Pro becomes even better.

Answer (score 2):

Well, LiberKey is a similar software and all apps installed with it are portable, i.e., you can copy LiberKey folder to pendrive, to other computers... and all will be in order. And it is free.

Answer (score 1):

What about https://chocolatey.org/ ?

After installing the software, you could script the installation of each software that you need. Didn't test it myself but it's free and easy to use.